# Finding PFCurrentUser in a TableViewController Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

I have different imageviews and labels displaying all users from a Parse class. I want to know how to get PFCurrentUser from a TableViewController - any sample code would help.

Thanks,

Comment: Your question needs to be specific or else you won't get specific answers. You stated you have different image views & labels displaying _all_ users from a Parse class. But your question says you want to know how to get PFCurrentUser from a TVC. What do you mean by "_from a TVC_"? a certain spot? a certain index? a certain cell?

Comment: You can get the get the current user in any class that has imported the parse headers with `[PFUser currentUser];`

Comment: Hi Soulshined, a certain cell.

Comment: Nathan, welcome to SO, first tip use the @ symbol before you type a name so that person gets notified or else they won't know you commented back to them. Second, it sounds like you want to the user of the person who posted the image in the imageView of a particular cell. For that your going to have to get used to PFRelations or pointers because there will be no way of you knowing who posted it without a relation to them being set. It's fairly easy to follow look at Parses docs or examples

Comment: @soulshined the PFCurrentUser keeps displaying as null - I'm using prepareForSegue and NSindexPath?